# How to Remove Background Images for free?

Tags: images

Can you suggest some free tools to Remove Background Images?

Comment: Could you please post an example picture, and say what parts should be removed? For instance, should only human faces subsist? Thanks!

Comment: Further: on what OS must it run? Btw: if you just want to remove the background images, each OS ships with a tool for that: `rm` un Linux/Unix, `del` on DOS/Win, hit the "delete" key in the file explorer (optionally with the shift key held down) while you have the image selected…

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove the background *from* images, https://www.remove.bg/ does the trick.

Comment: Looks great (upvote), but may not be completely free. See [pricing](https://www.remove.bg/pricing)

Comment: You get 1 free image in good resolution. The next free ones will be low resolution (625x400 pixels).